# .Net install tools extensions for vscode don't work with setting dotnetAcquisitionExtension.existingDotnetPath = C:\\ local installation \dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, c#-devkit

How can I set vscode with c# devkit to use my local installation C:\Program Files\dotnet instead of downloading each time .Net runtime in the folder C:\Users${user}\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage.
but it looks like c# devkit ignore the local path.
. c# devkit always download .Net 7 but I need to use .Net 8.

I've tried to set the settings.json file:

```
"dotnet.dotnetPath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\",
"omnisharp.sdkPath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\8.0.101\\",
"dotnetAcquisitionExtension.existingDotnetPath": [
     {
       "extensionId": "ms-dotnettools.csharp",
       "path": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe"
     },
     {
       "extensionId": " ms-dotnettools.csdevkit",
       "path": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe"
     }
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps :

1. In your VSCode, Install the extension: C# and C# Dev kit by Microsoft (`ctrl + shift + x`) from the extension marketplace.
2. Open the Settings Section. `(ctrl + ,`) and open the `settings.json` file
3. Add the below settings inside of the `settings.json` file:

> ```
> "dotnet.dotnetPath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\",
> "dotnet.sdkPath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\8.0.101",
> "dotnetAcquisitionExtension.existingDotnetPath": [
>   {
>     "extensionId": "ms-dotnettools.csharp",
>     "path": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe"
>   },
>   {
>     "extensionId": "ms-dotnettools.csdevkit",
>     "path": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe"
>   }
> ],
> "dotnet.autoSdkDownload": false
> ```